# Ajax Call to load different categories in WordPress not being picked up for my custom filter page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, post

Hey So I currently have a blog page that I have coded myself and am trying to upload it to a WordPress website it has the template name and type from WordPress see below

```
/*
 * Template Name: blog-page
 * Template Post Type: page
 */
get_header();

require('blog/conn.php');
```

now the `require('blog/conn.php')` works and connects to the connection file however when I try to do my Ajax Call it doesn't and it is from `blog/loadfilter.php` when I hosted this on my localhost it all worked however I am assuming since my wordpress rewrites my url into / instead maybe that is the reason it doesnt pick it up? I'm just confused why the conn works but filter wont and gets a alert 404 not found

my code looks like this first HTML buttons to change the catagories

```
<ul>
   <li class='listcat'>
      <input type="button" name="all news" id="allnews" onclick="window.location = url;" value="All News">
   </li>
   <li class='listcat'>
      <input type="button" name="technologies" id="technologies" onclick="loadXMLDoc('Technologies')" value="Technologies">
   </li>
   <li class='listcat'>
       <input type="button" name="business" id="business" onclick="loadXMLDoc('Business')" value="Business">
   </li>
   <li class='listcat'>
       <input type="button" name="lifestyle" id="lifestyle" onclick="loadXMLDoc('Lifestyle')" value="Lifestyle">
   </li>
</ul>

<div id="SBElite" class="row main-content-blogs-row">
```

And the JavaScript is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function loadXMLDoc(valueFilter) {

    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = 'blog/loadfilter.php';
    var params = 'filter=' + valueFilter;
    http.open('POST', url, true);

    //Send the proper header information along with the request
    http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
       if (http.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
           if (http.status == 200) {
              document.getElementById("SBElite").innerHTML = http.responseText;
           }
           else if (http.status == 400) {
              alert('There was an error 400');
           } 
           else if (http.status == 404) {
              alert('nope');
           }
           else {
              alert('something else other than 200 was returned');
           }
         }
      }
      http.send(params);
   }

   //back to the all news page
   var url = 'example.com/blog/';
</script>
```

Comment: On what page (url) is your form hosted? You are not using an absolute path in your ajax request, so if it is hosted at yoursite.com/form, your ajax request will go to yoursite.com/form/blog/loadfilter.php not yoursite.com/blog/loadfilter.php as you might expect.

Comment: yes sorry so it would be like `example.com/blog-page.php` is the actual page and then the route for the filter would be `/blog/loadfilter.php` is on the same level as the actual page tho im not sure how wordpress has it on different levels im still new to wordpress

Comment: In that case, I would check if the file exists on the server side at all. Maybe something went wrong when uploading/deploying

Comment: @PärtJohanson so its `example.com/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen-child/blog-page.php` and then `example.com/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen-child/blog/loadfilter.php` that is the directory layout

Comment: @PärtJohanson yea it is i echo 'hi' and it does that

Comment: @PärtJohanson also when i put full url into this part `var url = 'blog/loadfilter.php';` i get error saying "something else other than 200 was returned" and when i just have the `/blog/loadfilter.php` i get error saying "nope (meanig it was a 404 not found)

Comment: Okay, so the relative url 'blog/loadfilter.php' is correct, your script probably just throws an error when you feed it some post data with your ajax request and works fine otherwise. I would recommend opening up the developer console to see exactly what is happening (... -> More Tools -> Developer tools) and what status code is returned.

Comment: @PärtJohanson so i did your dev tools and checked so my problem was i was leaving out the `/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen-child/` before i went to `blog/loadfilter.php` because that how it is hosted on WordPress thanks my man you helped a lot (is there any way i can hide that file path so people don't see if for safety issues?

Answer (score 0):

With Help from Part Johanson found out that the /blog/loadfilter.php was not the correct full relative path from WordPress so i Fixed it and it now works